# Calculating voltage on inverting and non inverting pins for an op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

How does he calculate Va and Vb here:

[image]

I understand the rest of the stuff after he figures out what Va and Vb are. But how do I figure out Va and Vb when not given the values ->

[image]

Comment: Hints: Va = Vb in all op-amps with feedback. The 6v is your Vref for the op-amp. The 2v is an offset current added to the inverting input, but it stays at 1v because the + input is at 1v. Since Va and Vb are fixed at 1v, the rest is just V/R values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the inputs are high impedance.  So if no current goes into +, then you have a simple voltage divider.  Vb is 1/(1+5) x6V=1V.  There is also essentially no voltage drop across the inputs when operating normally.  So Va is also at 1V.

Comment: oh so no current ever goes into the + and -?

Comment: There is a small amount of current that flows into the inputs, but it's on the order of nA. For the most part, when doing an analysis you can consider the inputs to be an infinite impedance (therefore no current flows into the inputs.)